# Strcmp not returning 0

Tags: c, string, file, parsing

I have a textfile that looks like this:

```
TEMP:88
TT:33
3d;3d:5
```

I'm trying to parse the first line only, and check that it is indeed "TEMP:88"

This is what I tried:

```
FILE * file = fopen("test.txt","r");

if(file == NULL)
    exit(0);
char buff[128];

while(fgets(buff,sizeof(buff),file) != NULL) {
     if(strcmp(buff,"TEMP:88") == 0) 
         printf("TRUE");
     else
         printf("FALSE"); //prints false, regardless of newline character, use of memcopy or anything else
     break;
}
```

Then I tried to add the new line character "\n" inside the strcmp which yielded the same results, and mem copy also yielded the same result, any ideas?

Comment: try print the content of buff (better to print the ascii code)

Comment: It prints the correct string "TEMP:88"

Comment: The `\n` *should* be included; accounting for that, the comparison works as expected here: https://ideone.com/WY3OHM

Comment: `"TEMP:88"` is not the same thing as `"TEMP:88\n"`. *(even though they look the same)*

Comment: If including the newline in the string didn't fix it, maybe there are spaces at the end of the line.

Comment: Or depending on the type of system you are on, could it be that your file actually contains `TEMP:88\r\n`, with a carriage return as well as a line feed?  I second the suggestion of @BryanChen to print out the numerical values of the characters.

Comment: Try also printing `strlen(buff)`.

Comment: You should also consider using `strncmp` instead of strcmp which is dangerous because of buffer overflows. Using memset to zero `buff` could also help

Comment: @Eric `strcmp` is not dangerous so long as you pass null-terminated strings to it.  `strncmp` would not be any improvement and might introduce bugs (such as a partial match giving a false positive).

Answer (score 0):

From below source code

```
FILE * file = fopen("test.txt","r");
if(file == NULL)
    exit(0);
char buff[128];

while(fgets(buff,sizeof(buff),file) != NULL) {
    printf("%s,%d\n",buff,strlen(buff));
    int i= 0;
    while(i<strlen(buff))
    {
        printf("%d\n",buff[i]);
        i++;
    }
    if(strcmp(buff,"TEMP:88") == 0) 
        printf("TRUE");
    else
        printf("FALSE"); //prints false, regardless of newline character, use of memcopy or anything else
    break;
}
```

Its out put is,

> $ ./a.exe TEMP:88 ,9 84 69 77 80 58 56 56 13 10 FALSE

This ASCII values and string length shows your read string is not "TEMP:88". 
Read buffer contain ASCII values of LF and CR at the end.

So you can use

```
strncmp(buff,"TEMP:88",strlen("TEMP:88"));
```

Comment: You shouldn't get 13 in the output, unless you're opening a Windows text file under a non-Windows OS

Comment: I Know that. I just want inform him about "strncmp"

Comment: This usage of strncmp would also match `"TEMP:886"` for example

Answer (score -1):

Just to complement one of the comments above, quoting following link:

http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/cstdio/fgets/

> A newline character makes fgets stop reading, but it is considered a
>   valid character by the function and included in the string copied to
>   str.

So yes you should include the \n in the comparison

Comment: The question says that including the newline didn't make it work.

Comment: Just wondering if the end of line character in this case is not a Windows CRLF and not a LF char. Maybe this could cause the comparison to fail

Comment: That's another possibility.